# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found when migrate in laravel 5.4 project

Tags: php, laravel

following message appear on CLI when I want to migrate.

```
In Connection.php line 664:
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'kshitiz.migrations' doesn't exist in engine (SQL: select `migration` from `migrations` order by `batch` asc, `migration
  ` asc)

In Connection.php line 326:
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1932 Table 'kshitiz.migrations' doesn't ex
  ist in engine
```

how can I solve this?

Comment: Run `php artisan migrate:install` and then try to migrate.

Comment: when i run php artisan migrate:install following error message appear
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migrations' already exist
  s (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key,
   `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 c
  ollate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)


In Connection.php line 458:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'migrations' already exist
  s

Comment: So your table both exists and doesn't exist. Like a Schrodinger database table ? :O
Are you modifying the connection settings during runtime ?

Comment: What the command you used?

Answer (score 0):

Try wipe your database table if it's ok to do so. Let me know how it's going. I will edit my answer according to your action (can't give comment yet :p)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of possible reasons for this as you will find when doing a search.

When I had this problem it ended up being because I was accessing a model in a service provider.  I had to go into config/app.php and comment out the problem ServiceProvider::class before table creation.  Then uncomment it after `php artisan migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

Most simplest Solution is create another database with different name and Configure it with .env file and run the command.

```
php artisan migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably before `php artisan migrate` you run `php artisan schema:dump`

so go to `/database/schema` and delete `mysql-schema.dump` file and try again